# dynamic array getting "error code unspecified launch failure"

Tags: c++, cuda

i want to use dynamic array in my kernel with c variable, but i always getting this error "error code unspecified launch failure" when i use thread more than 1 threa. and if i comment this code c[letak] = 5; i did't get this error.

how to solve it?

```
__global__ void FillMatrix(char **sequence,int *s_length, int n, int *score)
{
 int b = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
 int a = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
 const int rows = s_length[a],cols = s_length[b];
  char *X = sequence[a];
  char *Y = sequence[b];

  const int jum = (cols + 1)*(rows + 1);

  size_t sizeArr = jum;
  int *c;
  c = (int*)malloc(sizeArr);
  memset(c,0,sizeArr);
  printf("Thread %d got C pointer: %p\n", threadIdx.x, c);
  score[(a*(n)) + b] = 0;
  if(b < n){
    printf("index ke %d - %d = %d --- %d - %d \n", a,b, jum, cols, rows);
    int letak,kiri,atas,miring, n_letak, n_atas, n_kiri,x=0,y=0,i;
    for(i = 0; i < jum;i++)
    {   
      if(i > (cols + 1 )  && (i % (cols+1) != 0))
      {
          y = (i/(cols + 1) - 1);
          x = (i-1) % (cols + 1);

          letak = i ;
          kiri  = letak - 1;
          atas  = (letak - cols) - 1 ;
          miring = atas - 1;
          int scoring = scoringsMatrix[X[y] - 'A'][Y[x] - 'A'];    
          n_letak = c[miring] + scoring;
          n_kiri = c[kiri] + GAP;
          n_atas = c[atas] + GAP;
          c[letak] = 5;
      }
    } 
    printf("score %d - %d = %d \n", a,b,score[(a*(n)) + b]);
    free(c);
  }
 }
```

Comment: This is C, not C++. And IMO this code is completely unreadable.

Comment: I suspect that you need `size_t sizeArr = jum*sizeof(int);` instead of `size_t sizeArr = jum;`

Comment: @razzorflame Strictly its C++ because variables like `letak` are not declared at the beginning of their scope. Obviously C style though.

Comment: Is it necessary to declare them in the beginning of the scope in C? I've never heard of that. Edit: why are you talking about so obscure facts from C89?

Comment: Its my kernel cuda . . When i move my variable, it still same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t sizeArr = jum;
```

is incorrect because you aren't accounting for the size of your array elements. Try

```
size_t sizeArr = jum*sizeof(int);
```

Comment: I also try this, but it still not resolve it. And getting error at memset